# Generating a sorted list of org-mode TODOs in multiple buffers

Tags: org-mode

I have hundreds of TODOs scattered across dozens of org buffers. Each of these TODOs has an associated priority. I would like to generate a master list of all these TODOs, sorted by priority. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TODO list obtained with `C-c a t` (bound to `org-todo-list`, assuming that you have bound `org-agenda` to `C-c a`) finalizes the list by calling `org-agenda-finalize-entries` which sorts the list using the criteria specified in the variable `org-agenda-sorting-strategy`. You should read its doc string (`C-h v org-agenda-sorting-stratey`) carefully. The default value for the global TODO list is `(priority-down category-keep)`. The simplest thing to do is to set the `todo` part of the variable to just `(priority-down)`:

```el
(setf (cadr org-agenda-sorting-strategy) '(todo priority-down))
```

This assumes that the second entry in the list is the `todo` part:

```el
((agenda habit-down time-up priority-down category-keep)
 (todo priority-down)
 (tags priority-down category-keep)
 (search category-keep))
```

That's the default, but you should check your value carefully just in case, and adjust the `setf` accordingly.

Given that you have hundreds of TODO entries and there are only three priorities by default, there will be a lot of entries with the same priority in the list, which you will probably want to sort on additional fields. Reading the doc string for `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` and experimenting is the best way to find the right settings for you.